# .NET IoC - Equivalent Code for .NET Unity

Tags: .net, configuration, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

In this Autofac IoC [article](http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/2/12/structuring-net-applications-with-autofac-ioc.html) they show an example of mapping an interface to an implementation with a parameter. You'll find it halfway down the article.

What is the Unity equivalent in XML? Can't use the fluent syntax for what I'm doing. Needs to be an external config file.

**UPDATE**:
This is the specific piece of code I want to know how to do in Unity -

```
<component id="DataStoreProvider"
 service="Company.Server.IDataStoreProvider,Company.Server.Interface"
 type="Company.Server.DataStoreProvider,Company.Server.Core">
  <parameters>
    <connectionString>My Connection String</connectionString>
  </parameters>
</component>
```

Maybe not the greatest example passing in the connection string this way... but you get the point. I'd like to know how to do parameters in XML in Unity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this. Refer to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440941.aspx) article

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    ...
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
    ...
</configSections>
...
<unity>
    <typeAliases>
      <!-- Lifetime manager types -->
      <typeAlias alias="singleton"  type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
      <typeAlias alias="external" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
      <typeAlias alias="ILoginService" type="Company.Shared.ILoginService,Company.Shared.Interface" />
      <typeAlias alias="LoginService" type="Company.Server.LoginService,Company.Server.Core" />
      <typeAlias alias="INavigationService" type="Company.Shared.INavigationService,Company.Shared.Interface" />
      <typeAlias alias="NavigationService" type="Company.Server.NavigationService,Company.Server.Core" />
    </typeAliases>
    <containers>
      <container name="Services">
        <types>
          <type type="ILoginService" mapTo="LoginService" />  
          <type type="INavigationService" mapTo="NavigationService" />
        </types>
      </container>      
    </containers>
  </unity>  
  ....
```

UPDATE: If you look into the MSDN article, there is a section that describes what I believe that fits your requirements.

```
<type type="IMyService" mapTo="MyDataService" name="DataService">
      <typeConfig extensionType="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.TypeInjectionElement,
                                 Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration">
        <constructor>
          <param name="connectionString" parameterType="string">
            <value value="AdventureWorks"/>
          </param>
          <param name="logger" parameterType="ILogger">
            <dependency />
          </param>
        </constructor> 
      </typeConfig>
    </type>
```

Comment: see update. Can you show me how to pass parameter in your XML that you posted?

Comment: Thanks, Vasu. Missed that in the first scan through. +1 and the win.